# ChartJS Different font size for X and Y axis

Tags: chart.js

Is there a way to have different font-sizes for X and Y axis using ChartJS.
scaleFontSize always applies to both axes.

I use the Y-axis with custom scaleLabel's which are LineIcons. I'd like to have those bigger while maintaining the size of the X-axis labels. A workaround will do as well.

Comment: i answered a question that wanted a similar feature to change the color of the y labaels but this could also be used to changed the font size http://stackoverflow.com/a/29099055/2737978, here is a fiddle using the example from that question but changing the font http://fiddle.jshell.net/54ta810r/1/